# Apache Camel Interceptor with regular expression

Tags: apache-camel

This is my route. I want to send a file to an Azure blob. I want to set the name of the blob as the file name without extension. I also want to filter out the whitespaces from the file names. I am thinking of using an interceptor

```
from("file://C:/camel/source1").recipientList(simple("azure-blob://datastorage/container1/${header.fileName}?credentials=#credentials&operation=updateBlockBlob"))
```

I want to invoke the interceptor only for updateBlockBlob operatin

```
interceptSendToEndpoint("^(azure-blob:).+(operation=updateBlockBlob)").setHeader("fileName",simple("${file:onlyname.noext}")).convertBodyTo(File.class)
```

The above code works with interceptFrom().

I tried replacing the regular expression with wild card like azure* i.e interceptSendToEndpoint("azure*"). It did not work

Whats wrong with the above code? Is it because of recipientList?

Also what features does simple have to remove white space?
Is there a better way to generate blob names dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation from camel on interceptors.

http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html

- interceptFrom that intercepts incoming Exchange in the route.
- interceptSendToEndpoint that intercepts when an Exchange is about to 
  be sent to the given Endpoint.

So I suspect the Exchange is already formed and camel expects the url to be resolved.
So the header needs to be set before the exchange is created for the Azure end point.

I did the following. To set the header, I use the interceptFrom, and to convert the object into File I used the inteceptSendToEndPoint

```
interceptSendToEndpoint("^(azure-blob:).+(operation=updateBlockBlob)").convertBodyTo(File.class)

interceptFrom().setHeader("fileName",simple("${file:onlyname.noext}".replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\d]")))
```

Managed to get rid of the whitespace too